# Identify Vertices intersecting with Bounding Box using Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Within Animation Nodes I have (a) the bounding box of an object I modeled and (b) random vertices from the "Random Vector" node. The random vertices appear inside and outside of the bounding box.

How can I remove all vertices, that are inside of the bounding box using animation nodes? So that the random vertices only appear outside of the bounding box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Is Inside Volume` node to know which vertices are inside the volume. Then use `Mask List` node to filter out vertices inside.

[image]